# Python list comprehension, and iterating

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, iteration

I was given a file with a 'grid' like design such as:

```
5,20,13
2,0,1,3,0
1,2,1,2,1
2,1,2,1,0
0,2,0,2,2
0,3,3,3,1
```

To make an attack simulator.
And that the first line represents n(Size of grid),p(Percent lost per square),k (Total number that must make it past the last line to win).

The issue I have ran into is the simulation part, I understand the fact of how to iterate of the lines of code and do the math to edit them such as:

```
numAP = numAttackPokemon
gridRules = gymData[0]    
gymGrid = gymData[1]      
n = gridRules[0]          
p = gridRules[1]
k = gridRules[2]          
numPRC = float(numAP/n) 
numPRCR = [numPRC] * n    

for numRow in range(0, n):
    gymGridNum = gymGrid[numRow]
    aList = []
    for num in gymGridNum:
        numDefSub = numPRCR[num] - gymGridNum[num]

        if numDefSub <= 0:
            print("You have failed, restart the program and try again!")
            break
        else:
            aList.append(numDefSub)

returns:
    [18.0, 20.0, 19.0, 17.0, 20.0]
    [19.0, 18.0, 19.0, 18.0, 19.0]
    [18.0, 19.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0]
    [20.0, 18.0, 20.0, 18.0, 18.0]
    [20.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 19.0]
```

Which is correct in the sense. But I also must apply a 'random' percent lost for each grid square, which I have done (not in that line of code, removed it to figure this issue beforehand). What I am trying to say is that I must edit the first line of this code (with the deduction of the number and percentage loss) then use that line for the rest of the grid repeating the math over again. I've became somewhat lost on how to keep, edit, and use a list for each row in the grid.

A correct output would be something like this, but without the random percentage loss: (numPRC = 100)

```
[18.0, 20.0, 19.0, 17.0, 20.0]
[17.0, 18.0, 18.0, 15.0, 19.0]
[15.0, 17.0, 16.0, 14.0, 19.0]
[15.0, 15.0, 16.0, 12.0, 17.0]
[15.0, 12.0, 13.0,  9.0, 16.0]
```

I have to re-use:

```
[18.0, 20.0, 19.0, 17.0, 20.0]
```

For the rest of the rows, but I'm not sure how to iterate with an updating list. I believe it is simple enough, but I am missing a small detail.

Comment: I'm a lot confused. You talk about making it past the last line to win. Should the results of one line (row) be affecting the next line (row)?

Comment: Also, should you be allocating your pokemon using floats? Or should you be doing integer allocations, with a possible remainder distributed across the row?

Comment: @AustinHastings The second line of the 'grid', [2,0,1,3,0], for each number must be subtracted from the numbers of attacking Pokemon. So yes the results of one line must affect the next. As for the Pokemon stored as a float my Prof. has said that these 'Pokemon'  are mutant, so some may not be a 'full' Pokemon and to use floats. Its very odd.

Comment: You can use generators to iterate over changing iterable, if this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, I think what you need is something like this:

```
attackers = [ numAttackPokemon / n ] * n
lost_per_square = 1.00 - p / 100.0


for row in grid:
    for col, cost in enumerate(row):
        attackers[col] *= lost_per_square
        attackers[col] -= cost
```

This will build a "row" of attacking pokemon, with the same number in each column. It will then iterate over each row in the grid, and for each row will iterate over each column, subtracting the grid's "cost" away from the corresponding column in the row of attackers.

In addition, it subtracts away a "losses per square". I'm guessing that this is what is meant by that, although I am not sure. Basically, if `p = 20`, then the losses per square would be -20%, and so the multiplying factor would be 1.0 - 0.20 = 0.80.

Please note: this applies the losses-per-square before any losses due to terrain. And it applies those losses even to the first square. You may with to change the order, and/or to skip applying the losses to the first or last square, depending on the problem statement.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It appears I didn't explain how 'p' worked properly but with the rest of the answer I was able to manipulate it to get the  outputs I needed. Thank you, I will submit the final code in another question to show the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Above this, Austin Hastings was able to help help solve my issue. I had to edit it for my desired outputs. The code follows bellow:

```
numAP = numAttackPokemon  # Number of Mutant Pokemon they wish to attack with
gridRules = gymData[0]    # Rules such as n,p,k
gymGrid = gymData[1]      # Gym Array
n = gridRules[0]          # Size of grid
p = gridRules[1]          # Number of defending Pokemon
k = gridRules[2]          # Number of War-Pokemon that must pass

attPoke = [numAttackPokemon / n] * n   # Number of Pokemon Per-Column-Row, Float value
randPerc = np.random.randint(0, n)
lossPerSquare = randPerc / 100.0

for row in gymGrid:
    for col, cost in enumerate(row):
        attPoke[col] -= cost
        attPoke[col] = attPoke[col] - (attPoke[col] * lossPerSquare)
```

Note: The variable 'p' acts as a random integer between *0 and n*, to which was to be used as a percentage, *lossPerSquare*. Then the final outcome of the total Attacking Pokemon was **(Attacking Pokemon - cost per square) - (Attacking Pokemon * lossPerSquare)**. Also the cost did need to come before the percentage lost, which I had forgotten to mention.

Thank you.